# How can get the div background image to scale to the page size?

Tags: html, css, image, scale

I am trying to make the background image of the div header scale to the size of the page. Here is the current css:

```
.Header {
    background-image: url(Images/logo.png);
    height: 160px;
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: `background-size: cover` perhaps?

Comment: This [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) article shows how to do it.

Comment: But beware, these things doesn't always work with all browsers.

Comment: @JoshCrozier When i add this, the background image does not show up at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the position as absolute of the header and width as 100%

```
position:absolute;
width:100%;
```

Comment: sorry does not seem to fix it. The image is repeated and when i change the size of the window, the image does not change size

Comment: means if you re size the window it goes multiple image ? can you give me the fiddle I'll try http://jsfiddle.net/