# Scale background img to the user's browser size

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I've went through all the relative answer in stackoverflow but haven't find the perfect fit. I am trying to make .background img fit the user's browser size no matter how user tries to resize the browser. Some relative questions are:

- [How can get the div background image to scale to the page size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653177/how-can-get-the-div-background-image-to-scale-to-the-page-size)
- [Fit website background image to screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925075/fit-website-background-image-to-screen-size)
- [Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only)

I am trying to create an effect similar to this site(it is mentioned on the Bootstrap official website as an example): http://riot.design/en/. Try to resize the browser and you will find out that the background img always scales and fits.

Is there a good way to achieve this effect?

Comment: that last 2 examples in your post is good. what don't you like about them?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/46t4qLfa/ this is what you need?

Comment: The background:cover; doesn't seem to work well.. I looking for the the same effect at the  http://riot.design/en/ . Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this in your css.

```
html { 
  background: url(http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/60/6975736-   
android-background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

there are many options you can choose from.. 
just try to follow them here that fits your needs.
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

litlitDM beat me to it while I was making a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfe196tj/). My code differs a little from his/hers. Be sure the url is in single or double quotes. Using the fallbacks provided by litlitDM is always a good idea. I like to use `postition: absolute` but as noted earlier css-tricks is a great resource as there are many ways to do this.